# How can I stop Grunt-spell from erroring incorrectly?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-spell

I'm using grunt-spell to check my jekyll `_site` HTML files after a build. It always works fine on the first file then errors on all but one other file with `Error: Unexpected close tag Line: 5 Column: 7 Char: >` the interesting thing is that all these files are made from a template and have  the first 10 lines identical.

If I delete the first file, then the second file works fine. If I delete the first two files the third file works fine and so on. It seems to me there is an error in grunt-spell, or teacher. Any ideas how to fix it or work around it?

Here is my grunt entry:

```
    spell: {
             files: ['./_site/**/*.html']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`grunt-spell` can only spell check plain text documents. You would need to first extract the text from the HTML and then feed to grunt-spell.

For common document types, html, markdown, etc... it would be nice to automatically parse out the spell checkable text. There is an open issue for it here: https://github.com/shama/grunt-spell/issues/7

Comment: It works great on the HTML files as long as they are individual. It's when I try more than one html file that it throws errors on the second HTML file. It sounds like you are saying it shouldn't work on my HTML docs at all?

Comment: Oh you're right, my mistake. I just looked into this and it looks like the After the Deadline API returns a 503 error upon subsequent requests. We should probably use a different spell check library or somehow batch all the files into a single request. Opened an issue here: https://github.com/shama/grunt-spell/issues/8

Comment: nice sleuthing! Looking through the code I think they are passed async. I wonder about delaying them somehow. I'll look into that. Maybe a grunt task that gets a list of **/*.html and feeds it one by one into spell...

Comment: [Concat](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-concat) will concatenate them but it seems it would be hard to find out which file had the spelling error...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working around it by commenting and uncommenting one at a time :(

```
            spell: {
//                     files: ['./_site/404.html']
//                     files: ['./_site/About/index.html']
//                     files: ['./_site/for-businesses/index.html']
                    files: ['./_site/for-developers/index.html']
//                    files: ['./_site/for-individuals/buy/index.html']
//                    files: ['./_site/for-individuals/faq/index.html']
//                    files: ['./_site/for-individuals/index.html']
//                    files: ['./_site/index.html']

                     //files: ['./_site/**/*.html']
            }
```

Kyle figured out this problem is caused by the After the Deadline API giving a 503. I think it could be fixed by using [grunt-filetransform](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-filetransform) first and capturing the filename, but I"m just switching to [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)

I've got spellcheck working better than I did in Grunt. See here if you are interested: [How do I output gulp results to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468310/how-do-i-output-gulp-results-to-console)