# How can I pipe the output from gulp-w3c-css to the console

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, csslint

When I follow the examples for [gulp-w3c-css](https://github.com/gchudnov/gulp-w3c-css) I am unable to get the results to print in the console instead of in an output directory.

Compare how I am using CSSLint and W3C-CSS below. I'd like the function to be identical.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    csslint = require('gulp-csslint'),
    cssvalidate = require('gulp-w3c-css');


gulp.task('csslint', () =>
    gulp.src('testcss/laxhjalpen.css')
    .pipe(csslint('.csslintrc'))
    .pipe(csslint.reporter())
);

// Does not work
gulp.task('cssvalid', () =>
    gulp.src('testcss/*css')
    .pipe(cssvalidate())
    // Next line works but is not what I want
    .pipe(gulp.dest('reports'))
    // I suppose I need to get this construct to work but I can't
    .pipe(gutil.buffer(function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            gutil.log('An error occured', err);
        } else {
            // No idea what to write
            // files - array of validation results (from manual)
        }
    }))
);
```

The very best solution would be just to have a reporter function that works like the *csslint.reporter* does.

Comment: Can you use this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470353/1241736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gulp-w3c-css` plugin serializes the validation results for each file to JSON and stores that JSON in the [`file.contents`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#optionscontents) property. The format of that JSON serialization looks roughly like the following (for more details see the [`w3c-css` documentation](https://github.com/gchudnov/w3c-css#css-errors--warnings)):

```
{
  errors: [ { line: 5, message: 'Some error' },
            { line: 42, message: 'Some error' } ],
  warnings: [ { line: 13, message: 'Some warning' },
              { line: 23, message: 'Some warning' } ]
}
```

So all you have to do is parse that JSON and then log the information to the console in any way you want.

Here's a simple example of how you could do it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssvalidate = require('gulp-w3c-css');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var map = require('map-stream');

gulp.task('cssvalid', function () {
  return gulp.src('testcss/*css')
    .pipe(cssvalidate())
    .pipe(map(function(file, done) {
      if (file.contents.length == 0) {
        console.log('Success: ' + file.path);
        console.log(gutil.colors.green('No errors or warnings\n'));
      } else {
        var results = JSON.parse(file.contents.toString());
        results.errors.forEach(function(error) {
          console.log('Error: ' + file.path + ': line ' + error.line);
          console.log(gutil.colors.red(error.message) + '\n');
        });
        results.warnings.forEach(function(warning) {
          console.log('Warning: ' + file.path + ': line ' + warning.line);
          console.log(gutil.colors.yellow(warning.message) + '\n');
        });
      }
      done(null, file);
    }));
});
```

I used [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream) instead of [`gutil.buffer()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#buffercb) so that the results for each file are printed as soon as they are available instead of printing everything at the very end.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to write a similar function for the HTML validator. However, there is no output when they are invoked using gulp.watch. See my [tests at GitHub](https://github.com/itpastorn/gulp-w3c-css-test/tree/1ef5ca8691abf5c040911ab35ef8679d29aa3887). But this is probably a separate issue.